# “No module named mayavi.mlab”

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

Estou tentando instalar o PyLayer no Ubuntu Xenial, mas quando tento exportar o coverage pelo

```
from pylayers.antprop.coverage import *
```

O seguinte erro aparece:

```
no module named mayavi.mlab
```

Mas eu tenho instalado o mayavi e não tenho acesso ao código fonte. Então, como eu instala essa dependência sendo que a tenho instalada.

Comment: Já tentou: pip install mayavi